# Circuit Anaylsis

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, dc

I have a simple but yet tricky circuit that i like to know how to approach. It is a circuit with a dc supply of 12 V and two identical resistors of 1kOhm. The circuit is constructed with both resistors connected to each end of the power supply and with both resistors end connected to ground. Is both sides before the the resistor have a voltage of 12 but negative of each other?

I have also done a simulation but its telling me each resistors voltage drop has 6V and -6. How can this be when the Voltage difference for both resistors is 12V to 0 and 0 to -12V?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjgEvzm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There is within the editor a scheme circuit editor, please use that, it makes it immediately clear what you ask.

Comment: Edited. Circuit added.

Comment: Your mistake is thinking that the voltage on the resistor is + or - 12V. The voltage source is not directly connected to ground, so neither side of the voltage source is necessarily at 0V.

Comment: Im sorry, what I meant was that the voltage drop on r1 is 12 volts since 12-0 is 12. This is same when looking at r2 but 0-12 = -12.

Comment: You are tripping over your own brain. Please reset it and look at this from another point of view. Compared to ground, a meter will show -6 volts and +6 volts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8JTC9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1.*

- If you had been presented with Figure 1a you would have no difficulty in realising that VM1 (voltmeter) would read 6 V and VM2 would read 6 V.
- With the add addition of a ground reference point in (b) we measure all voltages with respect to that. (e.g., Connect your black multimeter probe to the GND reference point.) Now the red lead will measure +6 and +12 V.
- If we move the ground reference to the positive terminal as in (c) the two voltage readings become -6 V and -12 V.
- Finally, if we ground in the middle as in (d) then we have +6 V and -6 V with respect to ground as shown.

[image]

*Figure 2. A multi-story building analogy.*

In Europe the ground floor in a multistory building is floor 0. All other floors are measured relative to that. On a 12 story building completely above ground all floor numbers will be positive 0 to 12. On a 12 story building with floors only below the ground floor all floor numbers will be negative, -1 to -12. If we have 12 floors but six floors are above and six below then we have floors -6 to +6. Same building just different zero reference. It's the same with voltages. We measure *relative* to some reference point and in most circuits a ground is defined and marked as such.

Does that make it clear?

Comment: Yes it is,  does that mean power on r2 would be negative?

Comment: No because the voltages point the same direction (up as shown in the diagram - the top of both resistors is at a higher voltage than the bottom) and the current flows the same direction through both (from battery + to battery -). If the power going into the resistor was negative it would mean that it was a generator somehow.